# Preparing variables, in Model or Controller?

Tags: variables, separation-of-concerns, date-formatting

I was wondering where should I prepare my variables in my MVC project. I have a form which post a date in this format : 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii' and i'd like to add ':00' at the end. Where am I supposed to do so ? In controller, and send the final data to my model, or my controller send raw data to model, and model should prepare the variables before inserting in db ?

What is the best practice ?

Comment: Within domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it in the model, which is historically where application data, business logic, etc., should live.